# better way to insert data in database with angular

Tags: angularjs

i have a form with 12 field (or more than that) and i want to insert data with angular to database .

i know what the way is :

```
$http.post('post_es.php', {'uname': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword}
                    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.msg != '')
                        {
                            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                        }
```

but i'm looking for a way that post all data from form whitout define each by each field like this :

```
{'uname': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword}
```

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm this might help

Comment: thx ,but he defines the value too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to better organize the code

```
var values = [
  'uname': $scope.username,
  'pswd': $scope.userpassword
];
```

And

```
$http.post('post_es.php', values).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.msg != '')
          {
             $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
          }  
}
```

Comment: thx,so there is no way to not define value ? or maybe my qustion is false .

Comment: no you have to put the db names on the left and their corresponding values on the right like this.  If not it won't know where to put the data.