# Angular JS - submit form in two different sections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form divided into two different sections and and I'd like the user to click "edit" next to a section and then submit only that part of the form. I've done this a bunch of times with jquery but I'm a fairly new to angular and I can't find/think of the correct way. Also, **this needs to be done programmatically**, since there are more inputs and potentially more sections that will be added to the form. Any help much appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT:**
just to clarify, my question is: how could I submit the form but only post the first row of inputs, or only the second row of inputs

**EDIT:**

Ok this is my latest thought on how to accomplish this...

I'm trying to send a form in two different sections. I was thinking I could wrap each part of the form in a separate controller, then do the $http request inside of a factory/service called "sendForms" (which one of these is the right way, factory or service?) and then set the form data to this.formData inside the factory/service. Then use ng-model="formData" on all the inputs and use ng-submit="sendForms" on the form element. Am I on the right track here? I did not update the code to look like this yet.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form id="edit_profile" ng-submit="processForm()">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 form-group input-text">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input id="first_name" name="first_name"
                               type="text" ng-disabled="toggleinput"
                               class="act_setting"
                               ng-model="userDetails.first_name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 form-group input-text">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input id="last_name" name="last_name"
                               type="text" ng-disabled="toggleinput"
                               class="act_setting "
                               ng-model="userDetails.last_name">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 form-group input-text">
                        <label>Address 1</label>
                        <input id="address1" name="address1" type="text"
                               ng-disabled="toggleinput"
                               class="act_setting "
                               ng-model="userDetails.address1" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 form-group input-text">
                        <label>Address 2</label>
                        <input id="address2" name="address2" type="text"
                               ng-disabled="toggleinput"
                               class="act_setting "
                               ng-model="userDetails.address2">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope,$filter,$http) {
        $scope.toggleinput = false;
        $scope.userDetails = {
            "user_id": "1",
            "address_id": "1",
            "first_name": "patrick",
            "last_name": "lawler",
            "email": "test@mail.com",
            "dob": "1991-06-04",
            "address1": "maple street 5",
            "address2": "apt 4",
            "country_code": "104",
            "state": "illinois",
            "zip": "987654",
            "time_added": "2014-11-20 23:42:02",
            "country_name":"Israel" };

            $scope.processForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/profile',
                data: $.param($scope.userDetails),  // pass in data as strings
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (!data.success) {
                            // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                            console.log('submit errors')
                        } else {
                            // if successful, bind success message to message
                            $scope.message = data.message;
                        }
                    });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why dont you use two button ?

Comment: Yes, I plan on using two "submit" buttons, there would be a "save" button next to each section, but how would I dynamically change the form data? right now if the form is submitted, the entire array of \$scope.userDetails is posted, I'd like to post only the inputs from one section of the form. Is this a realistic goal with angular or should I go back to jquery?

Comment: check this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200495/better-way-to-insert-data-in-database-with-angular

Comment: What if I put each section of the form inside a different controller? Then I put the $http request inside a directive and define the form data inside the directive and set it to this.userDetails? would something like that be ok to try?

Comment: sorry, I think I meant a service, rather than a directive

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right .
you need to define two button like:

```
<button ng-click="saveFirst()">Save First</button> 
//define second   
<button ng-click="saveSecond()"></button>
```

**js**

```
$scope.saveFirst = function(){

 $http.post('post_es.php', {'firstname': $scope.userDetails.first_name, 'lastname': $scope.userDetails.last_name}
                    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {}

}
```

and check this [Site](http://devzone.co.in/angularjs-simple-example-post-data-php-page/)

hope it'll help you

Comment: If I did this, not only would I have to create a second function called $scope.saveSecond(with a second $http request in it) but I'd also have to manually declare the name of each input. I don't want to do either of those things... Also, I feel like this totally defeats the purpose of data-binding with angular...

Comment: There has got to be a way to only use one $http request, and one processForm() function, and one form data variable, and just dynamically change the value of the form data depending on which "edit" button was clicked...

Comment: the way you want is coool, but i don't think it's possible

Comment: alright well thanks anyways :) maybe somebody else will have another idea

Comment: wlc :) , btw don't go back to jquery